# C multidimensional array heap assignment

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

I have a bunch of multidimensional arrays in C.

They look like this: (they are chars because ints in c take 4 bytes of memory instead of 1 byte for chars they are not used as strings)

```
char booting[96][25] = {{0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00},{0x00,0x18,0x18,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00},{0x06,0x7e,0x7c,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00} ... .. ..
```

They are 2400 chars long and I have many of them.
If I do this with a couple of them it works ok and i can acces them with:

```
char current_pixel = booting[34][2];
```

But after 9 or 10 arrays defined like this although it compiles ok, at runtime I get a StackOverflow error.

Question is: What is a better way to assign them on heap and to still keep accessing them like they are normal arrays on stack?

ps. I have looked around but still did not find exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for bearing with me!

Comment: `char (*booting)[25] = calloc(96,sizeof *booting);`

Comment: Most compilers have a way to increase the stack size.  If you really do want to heap allocate them then the question is: do they all have the same shape or do all of the dimensions vary in size?

Comment: they have the same structure and size, just different data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
vector< vector< char > > booting(y_size, vector< char >(x_size, starting_value));
```

Access this way (x and y may be opposite to what you expect)

```
for (int y = 0; y < y_size; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < x_size; x++)
    {
        cout << booting[y][x];
    }
}
```

Comment: The question states C, though the tags did originally include C++ too.  Don't down-vote this answer because it uses C++.

Comment: it's ok i can compile with c++ also. it's a mixed project.

Answer (score 5):

Either declare them as a global variable or as `static` so that they don't take up stack space:

```
static char booting[96][25] = { { 0x00, ... }, ... };
```

Or use `malloc()` for dynamic memory allocation:

```
char (*booting)[25] = malloc(96 * sizeof(*booting));
```

Comment: What's wrong with his code? Why should he use static or malloc? Is just `char booting[96][25] = {{}...}` not ok?

Comment: @LidongGuo Not if it's too big and overflows the stack.

Comment: @NeilKirk The size of stack is limited by OS or compiler?

Comment: stack size is limited by os. In linux i think you can set it at kernel compile!

Comment: unfortunately i cannot use static as they are declared in a file other than the main.